# Integrating the alternating tensor over a sphere

Tags: integration, tensors

I'm having some trouble working out how to evaluate

$\int_S\epsilon_{ijk}x_kdS$, where S is the unit sphere.

My thoughts are that $x_kdS$ is the surface element, but the combination of that with the alternating tensor is confusing me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute first the integral
$$\int_S x_k dS$$
which is obviously zero for any $k$
then it will be of course zero after construction with any other tensor.

Comment: Aaah, ok. I think you're right :) Thanks

Comment: I have a related question. Would the same logic apply to $\int_Sx_ix_kdS$?

Comment: For this one $i$ and $k$ should be the same otherwise it is again zero by the same logic. So it must be $\frac{\delta_{ik}}{3} \int r^2 dS=\frac{\delta_{ik}}{3} \int dS=\frac{\delta_{ik}}{3} 4\pi$

Comment: great, thanks a lot :)